# Concluding supremum from a condition

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $0\leq f(x) \leq s$

where $ \ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

and we define $ X = \big\{  \ f(x) \ :  \ x\in \mathbb{R} \big\} $

Now for any given $\epsilon>0   \ \ \ \   \exists u\in \mathbb{R}$

with  $s-\epsilon >f(u)$

Is this enough information to conclude that $s = \sup X$?

NOTE: I am aware that if the inequality were the other way round, then we have a conclusion.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $s-\epsilon<f(u)$?..

Comment: I am aware that this is a necessary condition for a supremum, but no, there were no typos here

Comment: We have that for any given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $u\in\mathbb R$ such that $s-\varepsilon>f(u)$. Take $\varepsilon>s$. What do we get now?..

Comment: I am assuming that you are referring to the fact that we are saying that a negative is greater than a positive? 

It is standard notation, that $\epsilon$ means 'a small increment'. Indeed if you fix an epsilon that works, than any epsilon smaller will also work...

It wouldn't make sense to take epsilon to be the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

No, we do not have enough information. Take $f(x)=1/2$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ and choose $s=1$. Then $0\le f(x)\le 1$ and for every $0<\varepsilon<1/2$ there exists $u\in\mathbb R$ such that $s-\varepsilon>f(u)$, but $s$ is not the supremum of $X$. We can also construct an example when $s$ would be the supremum of the function. Take, for instance, $f(x)=1+\sin x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$ and $s=2$.

Comment: Assume that we know that $s$ is an upper bound. Question has been edited.